# Python QGIS plugin could not load on linux build in window

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7, ubuntu, pyqt

I have created a plugin in QGIS windows version using
**"Plugin Builder"**. which on a button click opens another window, that is calling another class in the dialgoue python file, with another **.ui** file. That plugin is working fine on windows but when i installed that plugin on linux QGIS i got below error

```
Couldn't load plugin tplUserStatsReport due to an error when calling its initGui() method 

TypeError: Expected bytes or unicode string, got newstr instead 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 342, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName].initGui()
  File "/home/hasan/.qgis2/python/plugins/tplUserStatsReport/tplUserStatsReport.py", line 203, in initGui
    self.setInitialStats();
  File "/home/hasan/.qgis2/python/plugins/tplUserStatsReport/tplUserStatsReport.py", line 330, in setInitialStats
    connect= psycopg2.connect("dbname='"+str(Configuration.dbname)+"' user='"+str(Configuration.username)+"' host='"+str(Configuration.host_ip)+"' port="+str(Configuration.port)+" password='"+str(Configuration.password)+"'")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 129, in connect
    dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py", line 155, in make_dsn
    parse_dsn(dsn)
TypeError: Expected bytes or unicode string, got newstr instead


Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] 
QGIS version: 2.18.2 Las Palmas, 102ee87 

Python Path:
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/hasan/.qgis2/python
/home/hasan/.qgis2/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/hasan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache-1.50.1-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/home/hasan/.qgis2//python
```

How can i resolve this conflict that is occuring due to a plugin build on  windows and run on Linux?

Comment: I cannot tell from your error but are you using Python 2.7 with the `__future__` package with `unicode_literals`?

Comment: I don't know about __future__ package

Answer (score 2):

The problem is addressed in the error: it is a TypeError.  Your connection string is of the class `newstr`, not `unicode` or `bytes`.

The `__future__` package provides unicode utilities to Python 2 and overrides `str()` but now the class is of `future.types.newstr.newstr`.

While `future.types.newstr.newstr` has inherited from `unicode` it seem that the psycopg2 package doesn't check to see to see if the connection string is `isinstance()`.  Perhaps the `__future__` package isn't something that was depended on to remain stable during the development of Python 3 and documentation wasn't amazing.  It wouldn't be good to base your API on an unstable feature for easy unicode usage.

Try explicitly encoding the connection string by calling the `encode()` method, [which returns bytes encoded in utf-8](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/blob/master/src/future/types/newstr.py#L179).

I cannot see your code and my Python skills are super rusty but I believe this is the cause of your error.  Why does this not happen on Windows?  ...not sure maybe the Linux packages of Python are more strict, and I am not sure which version of Python your are using with QGIS on Windows.

---

More reading:

- http://python-future.org/str_object.html
- http://helpfulsheep.com/2016-04-06-future-proofing-python-2-code/
- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html?highlight=parse_dsn#psycopg2.extensions.parse_dsn

Comment: I have QGIS 2.18